# Given prime $p$, for any integer $a$, exist integer $x,y$ such that $p\mid y^2+x^3+a$.

Tags: contest-math, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be prime number and $a$ an integer. Show that the  equation
$$y^2+x^3+a\equiv 0\pmod p$$has integer solutions.

It seem a famous problem? But I can't prove it.

Comment: Hasse-Weil bound on the number of points on an elliptic curve gives this immediately when $p\ge5$, and you can brute force $p=2$ and $p=3$. When $p\equiv-1\pmod6$ it's trivial, because cubing is then injective modulo $p$. The case $p\equiv1\pmod 6$ is tougher with only elementary tools (read, I don't see it right away, e.g. Cauchy-Davenport is not enough).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,can you give the detail solution,and this problem is contest problem

Comment: Which contest? Can you give a link?

Comment: Thanks. So the contest was held today (in the now removed link there is a photo of the exam paper dated August13, 2017).

Comment: yes,it's today exam end

Comment: Hey, this might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus

Comment: Are we supposed to prove that $x$, $y$ can only be integers, or that it is possible that some $x$, $y$ are integers?

Comment: The solutions to the related problem at the last few pages of http://imo-official.org/problems/IMO2012SL.pdf should be amenable to rewriting for the current problem.

Comment: @wightahtl Have you got the answer to this problem yet? Any headway you have made? As said earlier, it's enough to examine $p \equiv 1 \mod 6$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Nice, that solution does also work for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions to problem N8 of the [53rd IMO](http://imo-official.org/problems/IMO2012SL.pdf), as mentioned by Gerry Myerson, do indeed apply to this problem. In fact it can be generalised. For any strictly positive integer $n$ and prime power $q=p^m$, then for any element $r$ of the finite field $F_q$ of size $q$, the equation
$$
y^2+x^n=r\qquad{\rm(*)}
$$
has solutions for $x,y\in F_q$, so long as $q$ is large enough. I'll show that $q\ge 2n^2-3n+2$ is enough.

In the question above, we have $n=3$ and, using mod-$p$ arithmetic is the same as working in the field of size $p$, so there are solutions whenever $p\ge 11$. This only leaves $p=2,3,5,7$ to be checked by hand.

As the case with $n=1$ is trivial, I'll assume that $n>1$. Also, if $q$ is a power of $2$ then squaring is injective in $F_q$, so (*) has solutions with $x=0$. I will therefore assume that $q$ is odd. Let $N$ be the number of solutions in $F_q$ to
$$
a^2+b^n= c^2+d^n.\qquad{\rm(**)}
$$

**Upper bound for $N$**: First, let $k$ be the number of solutions to $b^n=d^n$. There is one solution with $b=d=0$. Then, for each $d\not=0$ there are at most $n$ possibilities for $b$. So,
$$
k\le 1+n(q-1).
$$
Similarly, replacing $n$ by $2$, there are at most $1+2(q-1)=2q-1$ solutions to $a^2=c^2$. Putting these together, the number of simultaneous solutions in $F_q$ to $a^2=c^2$ and $b^n=d^n$ is at most $(2q-1)k$.

Now looking at each of the $q^2-k$ solutions to $b^n\not=d^n$, we can write (**) as $(a+c)(a-c)=d^n-b^n$. There are at most $q-1$ possibilities for $a-c$, which uniquely determines $a+c$ and, hence, both $a$ and $c$ (this uses the fact that $q$ is odd, so we can divide by $2$ in $F_q$).
\begin{align}
N&\le(2q-1)k+(q^2-k)(q-1)=q(q^2-q+k)\\
&\le q(q^2+(n-1)q+1-n)\qquad{\rm(1)}
\end{align}

**Lower bound for $N$**: Letting $s_r$ be the number of solutions to $y^2+x^n=r$ in $F_q$, by counting the number of solutions to $a^2+b^n=r=c^2+d^n$ for each $r$, we have
$$
N=\sum_{r\in F_q}s_r^2.\qquad{\rm(2)}
$$
I'll calculate a lower bound for $N$ in the situation that there exists some $r\in F_q$ for (*) has no solution -- i.e., that $s_r=0$. Letting $(a,b)$ be a solution to $a^2+b^n=r$ and $z=t^{2n}\not=0$ be a $2n$'th power in $F_q$,
$$
(at^n)^2+(bt^2)^n=rz,
$$
from which we see that $s_{rz}=s_r$. As there are at least $(q-1)/(2n)$ nonzero powers of $2n$ in $F_q$, we get $s_r=0$ for at least $(q-1)/(2n)$ values of $r$. Applying Cauchy-Schwartz to (2),
$$
N\ge\frac1{q-(q-1)/2n}\left(\sum_{r\in F_q}s_r\right)^2.
$$
However, $\sum s_r$ is just the number of solutions to $a^2+b^n=r$, which is $q^2$. So,
$$
N\ge\frac{q^4}{q-(q-1)/2n}\qquad{\rm(3)}
$$

Finally, in the situation that (*) has no solution for some $r\in F_q$, we can combine inequalities (1) and (3) to get
$$
q(q^2+(n-1)q+1-n)\ge\frac{q^4}{q-(q-1)/2n}.
$$
Rearranging,
$$
q^3+2(n-1)^2q+n-1\le (2n^2-3n+2)q^2.
$$
As the final two term on the left are positive, this gives $q <2n^2-3n+2$.